# Simple JSON.NET serialization/deserialization example

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, drools

I've been searching the internet for literally hours trying to find a very simple example of serialization and deserialization with a JSON call in C#. After careful browsing and piecing together, I'd like to call a JSON (POST & GET) function in my webservice (see below).

Here's what I was able to piece together

This would be my service contract (IExecWebservice.svc)

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace _27963199
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IExecFunction
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{function}/{args}")]
        double CalcThis(string function, string args);
    }
}
```

In my main code I parse out the users request URI (IExecFunction.cs)

```
//user will send variables in REST URI http://myCalcServer/CalcThis/MethodA/10,20
using FunctionLibrary;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace _27963199
{
    public class ExecFunctionService : IExecFunction
    {
        public double CalcThis(string function, string args)
        {
             Type t = typeof(Functions);
             MethodInfo[] libraryFunctions = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
             string[] arguments = args.Split(',');

             //Missing piece of code where I split the URI for the JSON function that will POST the data object to be be calculated by the DROOLS/Rules Engine and the results passed back to the users web browser
...
         }
     }
}
```

Now in my separate function class I'd have something like this (Function.cs)

```
using System;
using newton.json;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace FunctionLibrary
{
    public static class Functions
    {
        public static double DoMathA(string url, string arg1, string arg2)
        {
            double d1;
            double d2;

            if (!double.TryParse(arg1, out d1) || !double.TryParse(arg2, out d2))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Arguments to function 'DoMathA' must be numeric.");
            }

            //Data Object Format "{'myData':{'Id':'5','var1':'10','var2':'90'}}"
            myCalcObject = "{'myData':{'Id':'5', & arg1 & :'10', & arg2 & :'90'}}"
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
            request.Method = "POST"; 
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"; 
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(data.GetType()); 
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
            ser.WriteObject (myCalcObject)
            String json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()); 
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()); 
            writer.Write(json); 
            writer.Close();
       }
}
...

//Missing piece of code where I want to return the results of the JSON PUT and GET to the calling webservice
//JSON output string looks like this {"YourResults":{"condition":"YourHairIsOnFire","alertlevel":100,"id":0}}
//return or parse (json) to XLMS on the users browser

 }
```

I need help filling in the blanks so that the request URI is parsed properly to be passed into the JSON function and the reply JSON string be translated back as an xlms on the users browser. Any thoughts?

Update: I tried getting just the JSON section to work as a standalone C# class but I get that "Expected class..." error when I compile it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(http://172.16.20.26:8080/myDrools/result); 
request.Method = "POST"; 
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"; 
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(data.GetType()); 
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
ser.WriteObject ("{'myData':{'Id':'5','var1':'4.5','var2':'8.7'}}")
String json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()); 
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()); 
writer.Write(json); 
writer.Close();
```

What Am I doing wrong here? How can I get an XMLS output from this?

Comment: I'm a little unclear of what you are looking for? Do you want to serialize some JSON into a C# type, and vice versa? Is that all you are looking for?

Comment: I've refined the question a bit. I need help filling in the blanks to properly parse my URI for the JSON services to POST and whose JSON output data object I can read or pass as an XLMS response for the browser. Maybe uploading my project may help. Any ideas where I can upload my .project for coders here too look at?

Answer (score 1):

You have several bits and pieces. If you glue them together it can work.

#### Service Interface

Make sure your interface is capable of returning an object that holds the data you expect to return. By making fields nullable you can have variations in how the result looks like.

Notice the `ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json` to have json as the returned content type.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExecFunction
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{function}/{args}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    Result CalcThis(string function, string args);
}

// the result class that actsd as an container
public class Result
{
    public Double DoubleResult { get; set; }
    public Int32 IntResult { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

#### Service Implementation

The service implementation is bit more involved because it first needs to parse the arguments and convert them to proper types. When that is done it can use reflection to find an appropriate method to call. The returned type is then converted/projected on the `Result`.

```
public class ExecFunctionService : IExecFunction
{
    // this is a GET  /fubar/1,2,3,4
    public Result CalcThis(string function, string args)
    {
        // function=fubar
        // args = 1,2,3,4
        var allargs = args.Split(',');

        // store each argument with their type
        var typeList = new List<Tuple<Type, object>>();
        // parsr to gind the best match
        foreach(var arg in allargs)
        {
            // convert each argument string
            // to a type that is supported
            int i;
            if (Int32.TryParse(arg, out i))
            {
                typeList.Add(new Tuple<Type,object>(typeof(Int32), i));
                continue;
            }
            double d;
            if (Double.TryParse(arg, 
                   NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
                   new CultureInfo("en-us"), 
                   out d))
            {
                typeList.Add(new Tuple<Type,object>(typeof(Double), d));
                continue;
            }
            // if all fails assume string
            typeList.Add(new Tuple<Type,object>(typeof(string), arg));
        }

        // find and call the correct method
        // notice that parameters and their type do matter
        // overloads of the same methodname with 
        // different types is supported
        // Functions is the static type with methods to call
        var method = typeof(Functions).GetMethod(
            function,
            BindingFlags.Static| BindingFlags.Public |BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, 
            typeList.Select(ty => ty.Item1).ToArray(), //all types
            null);
        var callresult = method.Invoke(
            null, 
            typeList.Select(ty => ty.Item2).ToArray()); // all values

        // shape the output in the form you need
        var result = new Result();
        if(callresult is double)
        {
            result.DoubleResult = (double) callresult;
        }
        if (callresult is int)
        {
            result.IntResult = (int)callresult;
        }
        if (callresult is string)
        {
            result.Message = (string)callresult;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

#### Your Functions to be called

This is the class that holds all your methods that can be called from the service.

```
// your calc functions go here
public static class Functions
{
    public static double DoMathA(double arg1, double arg2)
    {
        return arg1 / arg2;
    }

    public static double DoMathB(int number, double factor)
    {
        return number * factor;
    }

    public static int DoMathC(string somestring)
    {
        return somestring.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

#### What does it look like?

Calling `http://localhost/service1.svc/DoMathC/fubar` will return:

> `{"DoubleResult":0,"IntResult":418978654,"Message":null}`

and `http://localhost/service1.svc/DoMathA/2.5,3.4` will return:

> `{"DoubleResult":0.73529411764705888,"IntResult":0,"Message":null}`

and `http://localhost/service1.svc/DoMathB/4,3.5` will return:

> `{"DoubleResult":14,"IntResult":0,"Message":null}`

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: instead of trying to glue together a string, return an object. The service will take care of stringifying it for you.
So, create a class with properties to match the JSON object, and then set your values into those properties, then return the object. Done.
Don't overthink it